# verify SGX quote attestation with DCAP

Tags: sgx

I am new in SGX,In DCAP attestation a SGX quote is generated which is going to be used by the client to make sure the code or request is executed inside SGX so my question are:

- when attestations occurs, how the client car verify the quote?
- where the SGX quote is saved? how client can access it?